# How to use ng-table with webpack?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, ngtable

I'm trying to use [ng-table](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table) in my anuglarjs application. I didn't realize that [npm version is f up](https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter/issues/100) and new release is not there yet, however my app is in an advenced stage and I can not use bower vesion.

I was trying to load latest version from git `npm install git+ssh://git@github.com/esvit/ng-table.git --save`

and then load it in my entry file:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import ngTable from 'ng-table';

angular.module('app', [ngTable]);
```

Sadly webpack throw a lot of errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular'(...)
```

I was also trying to use imports-loader:

```
const ngTable = require('imports?define=>false,angular!ng-table');
```

but no success either. Could somebody points me in right direction? I really would like to not rewrite all chore stuff because of the one lib.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ng-table` like this:

```
// app.js
import angular from 'angular';
import ngTable from 'ng-table/dist/ng-table';

angular.module('app', [ngTable]);
```

since looks like doesn't have and index config for commonjs modules

check this comment https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/issues/764#issuecomment-184357333

Comment: Alright webpack build successfully pass, however there is an error in the console: http://i.imgur.com/P2T3N4x.png

Comment: sorry but can't figure out what's wrong, do you have a repo url?

Comment: I can upload to github the test I did earlier

Comment: Would be great, maybe I will find out why I'm getting this error

Comment: here is the repo https://github.com/IngenieroLata/test-ng-table let me know if have troubbles

Comment: Alright, I will see why now it's working and with previous version it wasn't. Thanks a lot with help!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find the solution as well. Here it is. 
"import" quiet does not work for me. Gives out an error

> webpack.config.js

```
config.resolve = {
  extensions: ['', '.js'],
  alias: {
    'ng-table': 'ng-table/dist/ng-table'
  },
  modulesDirectories: [ 'node_modules', 'bower_components' ],
};

config.module = {
  loaders: [{
    test: require.resolve('ng-table'),
    loader: 'imports-loader?define=>false,$=jquery,angular'
   }]
}
```

> app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);
```

`define=>false` was the one of key things which I was missing when following the github answer. and injecting `angular` into `ng-table` is being done in the loader line.